# How to store a XML file as a String in PHP

Tags: php, xml, string

Hello everyone I am trying to create a XML file as a string in php so then I can curl it up to our system for processing.

How come I can't just do this?

```
$XML = ' <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

All of the php code below seems to not want to be picked up anymore after this.

Why does this happen since the entire string is surrounded by ' ' ?

If there is a way around this please let me know.

Comment: Turn on error reporting and display errors on screen. If you get no subsequent output, something else may have gone wrong.  I'll note that the leading whitespace before `<?xml` is going to cause problems in most XML tools....  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Can we see the rest of the script?

Comment: that was it guys!!!  thank you the ?> was turning off php!!

Answer (score 1):

Use the [heredoc syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) :

```
<?php
$str = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding...
<partlist>
...
</babelpart>
XML;
```